# Cleaning up jobs and pods by age?

Tags: cron, openshift

Is there a way to `oc delete jobs` or `oc delete pods` by age? I want to clean up cron job artifacts by how old they are. Is that possible?

Edit: I added a python script that cleans up jobs below. It works. I was under the assumption that it would cleanup related pods too, but it does not. I realize that even though I asked about pod cleanup that trying to get that resolved maybe beyond the scope of a single answerable question, so when I get back to figuring this out I will ask a new question. Thanks to those that answered and helped steer me in the right direction.

Comment: What OpenShift installation are you using? For a complete installation, a periodic job should run at cluster level which goes around and cleans up certain things when they are older than certain time. If running on Minishift or ``oc cluster up``, I am not sure if this job runs or not. The command it uses is ``oc adm prune``, although looking at that I don't see anything about stopped pods from jobs. I will try and find out what happens with stopped pods for jobs.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I'm using v3.5.5.31, but I don't have admin privileges, so I have to find a different way to approach it. I'm going to look at your approach, but I also came up with my own approach which I will share when I have tested it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it took so long to get this up here. 
Since I don't have admin privileges and I already have python apps triggered by cronjobs on openshift, I thought the best approach was to use the [REST API](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/rest_api/index.html). That lead me to write this script that cleans up jobs that have completed and are older than 24 hours.

```
from os import environ
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

## Setup authentication token

```
apihost = 'https://openshift.redhat.com:8443{endpoint}'

jobsurl = apihost.format(
endpoint = '/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/%s/jobs' % environ['NAMESPACE']
)

headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % environ['AUTH_TOKEN']
}
```

## Get current jobs

```
req_jobs = requests.get(jobsurl, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

## Loop through, identify jobs to delete

```
jobstodelete = []

for item in req_jobs.json()['items']:
    if 'completionTime' in item['status']:
        elapsed_time = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(item['status']['completionTime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        if elapsed_time > timedelta(hours=24):
            jobstodelete.append(item['metadata']['selfLink'])
```

## delete jobs in set

```
for job in jobstodelete:
    delurl = apihost.format(
        endpoint = job
    )

req_del = requests.delete(delurl, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

This cleans up the jobs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Kubernetes documentation around cleanup of jobs is:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup

> When a Job completes, no more Pods are created, but the Pods are not deleted either. Since they are terminated, they don’t show up with kubectl get pods, but they will show up with kubectl get pods -a. Keeping them around allows you to still view the logs of completed pods to check for errors, warnings, or other diagnostic output. The job object also remains after it is completed so that you can view its status. It is up to the user to delete old jobs after noting their status.

So you would need to use `oc delete` to clean them up yourself.

The only way to do it appears to be to use a script (untested) something like:

```
for job in $( oc get jobs -o name ); do
   if [[ "$( oc get "${job}" -o jsonpath="{.status.conditions[0]['status','type']}" ) != "Complete True" ]]; then
       continue
   fi

   completionTime="$( oc get "${job}" -o jsonpath='{.status.completionTime}' )"
   if [[ "$( date -d "${completionTime}" +%s)" -lt  "$( date -d "${cutoff}" +%s )" ]]; then
       oc delete "${job}"
   fi
done
```

Comment: I read that. I was reading this [https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html], which basically says the same thing as far as a manual cleaning up of cron job artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

[docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc) can delete exited containers by how old they are via the `GRACE_PERIOD_SECONDS` variable. It will delete all the exited containers though, not just the cron ones but you might be able to make it work using the `EXCLUDE_FROM_GC` variable.

Comment: This is not plain old Docker service he is using, but OpenShift/Kubernetes. A tool like ``docker-gc`` is not going to do what is required.